# Decoding unicode code point into utf8 using ICU

Tags: c++11, unicode, utf-8, icu

I have a unicode character code point stored as a string.

```
std::string code = "0663";
```

I need to decode it into utf8 and get as a standard std::string using the ICU library.

I decided to use ICU to get a cross-platform bit-independent solution.

Comment: Is the string meant to represent [U+0663](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0663/index.htm) (٣ 'ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT THREE')?

Comment: Yes, I had an Arabic character unicode codepoint, but I received it as a string, contains number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

1. Convert the string into a `int32_t`.
2. Treat the `int32_t` as a [`UChar32`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/umachine_8h.html#a09fff5c3b5a5b015324dc3ec3cf92809).
3. Create a `UnicodeString` with [`UnicodeString::setTo`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#abb108d29fc9d103f53103d8a50291c79) from the `UChar32`.
4. Create a string object with [`UnicodeString::toUTF8String`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a64317c339e58e8b6135bd4341c6ccfd2) from the `UnicodeString`.